# Why does componentWillUnmount() not execute?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

In a project I'm using wix's RNN. In which I have a screen, lets call it 'Screen1'. Screen1 has a button that calls `Navigation.push()` and moves to 'Screen2'. Screen1 has an alert set in `componentWillUnmount()`. but when the screens change, the alert is never shown.

```
export default class Screen1 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    alert("Goodbye screen1");
  }
  nextScreen = () => {
    Navigation.push(this.props.componentId)
  }
  render() {
    <View style={{height: '100%', width='100%'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.nextScreen}>
        <Text>Test Button</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  }
}
```

I expect the alert to be fired when moving to the next screen. however, the the component seems to still be mounted because the alert isn't fired, and there's a function (not pictured) inside `screen1`'s componentDidMount() that is executing from the next screen. So how is wix handling the component lifecycle on screen changes?

Comment: If you notice.. you are doing a `Navigation.push` call. This is a stack of screens, so the prior screen is not actually unmounted but rather just running underneath the next screen that is pushed on. I'd have to look up the api docs (been 2 years since I used this) but I believe the `replace` method wipes the stack clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your component is still mounted. You just pushed another screen on top of it. It's not visible but still mounted.

I'm not a specialist on RNN, but I think what are you looking for is the [componentDidDisappear](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/events?id=componentdiddisappear)  event.

Hope it helps.